# Monthly maximum values of summarized fields

Tags: crystal-reports

Good afternoon.  I am attempting to produce a report that shows monthly summaries of stock holdings.

The table I am using has the following data (datatype):
Site (string), Customer (string), Week Ending Date (int - YYMMDD format), Closing Balance (int)

And would look something like this:

```
Site Cust   Wk End  Bal

UK - Dave - 110821 - 25

UK - Sam - 110821 - 15

UK - John - 110821 - 30

UK - Dave - 110828 - 80

UK - Sam  - 110828 - 30

UK - John - 110828 - 10

UK - Dave - 110904 - 100

UK - Sam  - 110904 - 29

UK - John - 110904 - 51

UK - Dave - 110911 - 97

UK - Sam  - 110911 - 34

UK - John - 110911 - 12
```

What I am trying to find is the maximum weekly closing balance per site.  Such that it may display information like:

```
UK - 08/11 - 120

UK - 09/11 - 180
```

It needs to produce for each site, one line per month with the maximum week's total for that month.

The month/year formula is a couple of substrings from Week End to pull the month/year (remembering data is in YYMMDD format).

When I try this in crystal using groups across Site and the formula to produce MM/YY. I always receive "Cannot summarize this field" errors when trying to get the maximum of the month's weekly summary.

EDIT: I have written SQL to return one site's results. This may help explain the problem better.  Please see below:

```
  Firstly a definition for clarity MMYY=(substr(A.WEEKEND,3,2)||'/'||substr(A.WEEKEND,1,2))

    select distinct(MMYY) as Month, MAX(B.CLOSEBAL) as MonthMax
    from balance_file as A
    join(
    select MMYY as dte,
    sum(CLOSING) as CLOSEBAL
    from balance_file
    where SITE='UK'
    group by WEEKEND
    order by WEEKEND)
    as B on MMYY=B.dte
    where WEEKEND>110101 and WEEKEND<110505
    group by WEEKEND
    order by Month
```

Comment: I know you've got a working solution, but this is a great example of aggregates of aggregates and I think might benefit other people. Would you edit your example records above so the results correspond to the values of the input records?

Comment: Hi Noa,  I'm unsure of what you mean.  The two records displayed as "intended results" are the results required from the data set above.  The formula/method provided below will return a single result per month which is the maximum sum of the month's 4 weekly closing balances.

Unless of course I have completely misread your question; could you please elaborate?

Comment: I just realized the totals are correct. But the dates don't match.

Comment: Oh yes; how stupid.  I just have added a little more data to show two weeks for each month and made sure the dates reflect the real data.  Hopefully will be a bit clearer now.

Comment: Thanks. Would you change the date formats back, so they're consistent between the two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set up your groups: Create a formula to convert that Week Ending Date integer into a date. Now you can outer group on the site and inner group on the new date formula that you have just created. In the latter group, you can set to print by month (Group Expert -> Options -> "This section will be printed: for each month").

<strike>Next, it's only a matter of doing a maximum summary for each inner group on {table.close_balance}. (Insert Summary -> Field to Summarize: {table.close_balance}, Calculate this summary: Maximum, Summary Location: Group 2 {@DateFormula}).</strike>

Now each Group Footer 2 will show an entire month and the maximum weekly end balance in that month for each site.

OK, let's try this again.

In addition to the two groups above (Site and Month) you can add a final inner grouping by Week using the same formula. So G1 - Site, G2 - Month, and G3 - Week.

Create a formula, {@reset}, that can be placed in Group Header 2 and will reset the variable 'max'.

`whileprintingrecords; numbervar max := -1`

Create another formula that can be placed in Group Footer 3 that updates the 'max' variable when it is appropriate.

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar max;
local numbervar weeklySum := sum();
if max < weeklySum then max := weeklySum
```

Finally, create a third formula that can be placed in Group Footer 2 to display your monthly max summary.

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar max
```

Comment: Thanks for the response: however this method will only calculate the highest single customer closing balance per month.  It needs to calculate the highest week total for all customers together.

In your example it will produce
UK - 08/11 - 80 (Selects Dave's balance only),
UK - 09/11 - 100 (Selects Dave's WK 1 balance only),

Where it needs to produce
UK - 08/11 - 120,
UK - 09/11 - 180,

It seems crystal refuses to summarise summarys!

Comment: Why would it give totals per customer? My suggestion was to group on site and month only. Doing that will give you the maximum weekly balance per site regardless of customer. So, for example, UK-Dave-110904-100, UK-Sam-110904-29, and UK-John-110904-51 will all sort to the same inner group and the resultant MAX on that will be Dave's 100.

Comment: I apreciate the response and thank you for your help so far. I think my original question may be unclear.  I need to summarise the max week total of all customers per month.  

In the example above there are three records per week.  Assume there are 4 weeks per month.  I need to find the single week with the max balance.  The balance is a sum of all customer's balances for the week.  Imagine its a warehouse.  All customers stock is held in the warehouse.  I need to find the max closing total of stock for each warehouse for each month.  The SQL in my amended first post may make it clearer

Comment: OK, I think I see now. You're looking for the WEEK, not the actual value, that is associated with the highest weekly balance regardless of customer, is that right?

Comment: No; sorry again.  Its quite hard to explain! The end result will hopefully show: Site - Month - MAX(SUM(closing_bal, weeks in month)). Each month has 4 weeks, for each of these weeks there is a sum of all closing balances.  I need to return the highest summed closing balance per month.

Comment: Hi Ryan,  That's perfect.  The only thing I must add for people looking at this in the future is you must use SUM(field, breakfield), in my case SUM(CLOSING_BAL, WEEKEND).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a running total instead of a variable.

Write a formula `TotalClosingBal`:

```
Sum({ClosingBal}, {WeekEnd})
```

Then create a running total:

- Evaluate **Maximum** of `TotalClosingBal`
- On change of group `{WeekEnd}`
- Reset on change of group `{Month}`